# Identify this programming language, it uses a '.m' extension

Tags: programming-languages

```
len = length(range);
K = 2^nextpow2(2*len - 1);
halfK = round(K/2);
U = zeros(halfK, 1);
centfreqs = data.model.cochlea.centfreqs;

for i = 1 : data.model.cochlea.gt.nch % number of channels
    x = data.au(range, i).*window;
    X = abs(fft(x, K));
    bin = round(2*centfreqs(i)*K/data.fs);
%     if i==4 plot(X); pause; end
    X(bin : halfK) = 0;
    U = U + X(1:halfK);
end
U = U';
```

the code came from [here](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ftiendung%2Fmutiple-f0-estimation&ei=x2lfS5uLCIqUkAXP34zzCw&usg=AFQjCNF5YC7PN3KTivNXiFcll0kpBknF6g&sig2=o-UWxrs18xzVy2mWqd9FTQ)

Comment: You do realize it doesn't really matter what the extension is, as you can configure your server/computer to associate any compiler with any extension.

Comment: Cool! I want my server to run my C++ source files! How do I do that?

Comment: What if I don't have a server?

Comment: Yeah Yeah Yeah.... I made it more specific....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks to me like [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB).

Answer (score 9):

`.m` is used for either `matlab` or `objective-c`

I don't remember how matlab looks like in detail, but
looking at the link it seems like `matlab`.

Comment: When I read ".m", I thought "Obj-C". When I saw "%", I thought "MATLAB".

Answer (score 3):

It's a MATLAB file. You can verify this if you read the Report in the docs folder of the project.

Answer (score 2):

looks like matlab.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say Mathematica but there are far too few square brackets. =) Definitely Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Thankfully it's not [MUMPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS).

Comment: Frighteningly, Wikipedia lists 46 programming languages (including MUMPS) beginning with the letter 'M'...